# How to estimate what tier of hardware we'll need for AWS Aurora?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Are there any tools available (either from Amazon or from third parties) to help you estimate how much hardware your service will need to run on RDS Aurora? The AWS documentation is very good at describing "a large r4 instance costs $X/hour in each of these regions," but I can't find anything that helps you decide which tier of hardware your application will need.

I.e. our app has X writes per day writing Y GB of data, and Z reads per day reading out W gb of data, so do we need an r4.xlarge, or would an r4.large suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that attempts to tell you what type of hardware or instance type you need would be wrong because it always **depends upon your particular application and usage patterns**.

The best method is to **pick something, then perform load tests** that use your actual application to simulate actual traffic.

Fortunately, the cost of getting it wrong is relatively low -- you can later decide to scale-up or scale-down the database. Therefore, you could **start with something large and scale-in when you have a better understanding of your needs**. The extra cost is minimal compared to the real-world where you would have to commit to hardware purchases up-front.

Comment: Makes sense. I was still thinking in terms of committing to a certain hardware tier from the get go, but yeah I guess we can just scale up and down during testing and see where the sweet spot is. Thanks!